# Cyrillic - main settings for php, headers and mysql (is UTF8 the solution?)

Tags: php, mysql, html, encoding

I have a project where users are supposed to use special characters (cyrillic like 'Врати се на почетак' which means return to top for example). I will have to make some special settings and I need some advice regarding the proper encoding to use for my project:

1. **mysql database** - is it good to use this encoding `utf8_unicode_ci` or should I search to a specific one? (I did not find anything dedicated to cyrillic languages, but this review says it is ok to use this http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,187048,188748#msg-188748)
2. **php** - will this setting `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` be enough in php to parse correctly the mysql query response in my code?
3. **html headers** - would this header `<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">` suffice for the correct display and interpretation for both browsers and crowlers for my page?

Is there anything else I should be aware of in this issue?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is the better solution for Cyrillic chars in web. But you have to change this:

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

to

```
<META http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

And of course the source files must be saved with urf-8 enc set.

PS: If you are setting everything in utf8 there is no need of calling `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` Its necessary only if you  have inherited project with db in other encoding/converting old databases is sometimes nightmare/

Comment: I will try this but however I remember working on some hebrew website and it simply did not work until I made all the settings above but localized for hebrew. I will try that!

Comment: I depends if you are settign everything - if there is an old inserted data, or files, saved into different than utf8 encoding ... there is messed up data.
If you start a new project, if you set everything in utf8 you will have no problems ... even with Hebrew, Chinese or any other lang chars

Comment: It is **almost always** necessary to call "SET NAMES utf8" (or even better, `mysql_set_charset("utf8")`) because that's how you set the MySQL client encoding. Otherwise you are using what ever is configured as the default, which is likely not utf8, and that's the encoding MySQL will use when returning results. http://jonisalonen.com/2012/ultimate-guide-to-utf8-and-mysql/

Comment: NO quite true ... As I said if there are correct db settings, collations, etc there is no need to define something already specified, right ?